# Calculate a lag vector in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to calculate a lag array for a MongoDB array? For example, if I have a document:

```
{id: 542532gsegsegt32t2,
values: [1, 6, 2, 45, 6]
}
```

Is there a way to generate a result of a query that would be:

```
{values_lay : [5, -4, 43, -51]}
```

Calculated as `[6-1, 2-6, etc...]`...
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: why `6-1` then `2-6`? what is the logic here? where is `43` and `-51` coming from?

Comment: Do you know the array length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using aggregation framework, but imho it will be easier and more flexible when calculated on client/application side.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     $project:
      {          
         values_lay: [
                    { $subtract: [{$arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 1 ]}, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 0 ]}]},
                    { $subtract: [{$arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 2 ]}, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 1 ]}]},
                    { $subtract: [{$arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 3 ]}, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 2 ]}]},
                    { $subtract: [{$arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 4 ]}, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 3 ]}]},                    
                    ],

      }
   }
])
```

---

EDIT

my assumption: **as we have arrayA of N elements, we need to create arrayB of N-1 elementsts =>**

```
arrayB[1]   = arrayA[2]   - arrayA[1]
arrayB[n-2] = arrayA[n-1] - arrayA[n-2]
arrayB[n-1] = arrayA[n]   - arrayA[n-1]
```

Piece of js code which can be used server side/client side

```
db.hellob.find().forEach(function (doc) {
    var arraySize = doc.values.length;
    doc.results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) {
        doc.results.push(doc.values[i + 1] - doc.values[i])
    };

    printjson(doc);
})
```

Comment: The question is unclear as we don't know the logic here. What if OP doesn't know the array length?

Comment: @profesor79 Thanks for this feedback. I would like to do this in cases where I don't know the array length and where the array length can be different for each document.

Comment: @hellob are you sure that you need to do it database side?  You can use forEach but this is extra load,  which should be shifted to application

Comment: @profesor79 the second version works fine. Unfortunately the first version is giving me an error (for Mongo v 3.0.6 of "errmsg" : "exception: disallowed field type Array in object expression (at 'values_lay')",

Comment: @helloB  `$arrayElemAt` was introduced in 3.2 so that's the reason for you error. Happy to help!